# Hey guys i'm new to python,need some advice on this function

Tags: python

So i have created a function that adds data to an array list only if it does not already exist in the list already, If it does it should be ignored but if it doesn't it should be appended.

```
myUniqueList = []

def ListValues(addData):
    if addData in myUniqueList:
        return addData
        return False
else:
    myUniqueList.append(addData)
    return True
```

and i have created another function to append data that has been ignored in the first function to a second array called myLeftovers

```
myLeftovers = []

def nonunique(rejects):
    myLeftovers.append(rejects)

Var1 = ListValues("Hello")
Var2 = ListValues("Hello")
Var3 = ListValues("Hello")
Var4 = ListValues("hello")

print(myUniqueList)
print(myLeftovers)
```

How can i append data that was ignored in the first array list to the second list only using the second function.

Expected output
['Hello','hello']
['Hello','Hello']

Comment: expected output please

Comment: you will need to call `nonunique` function inside `ListValues` where you ignore the duplicate values.

Comment: By calling the second function inside if block itself

Answer (score 0):

You could simply modify the `ListValues` method to call the `nonUnique` method if the element is already found in the list:

```
def ListValues(addData):
    if addData in myUniqueList:
        nonunique(addData)      # call the nonunique method here
        return False
    else:
        myUniqueList.append(addData)
        return True
```